# Galaxy S3 Error/Crash Log Location

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, crashes, system-freeze

Is there an error log or crash log file anywhere on the Galaxy S3?

My phone is constantly crashing (rebooting or totally freezing requiring a battery pull) at least 4-5 time a day. I've attached the phone to my PC and browsed the file-system using Eclipse but I can't find an error log anywhere obvious.

My phone is NOT rooted so I realise I don't have total access to all locations on the phone's file-system but if anyone knows if such a log exists and where about it is, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: use `adb logcat` or [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) from play store, that will enable to save the log to SDCard... other than that, we cannot do anymore until a log is obtained

Comment: So with aLogCat, am I able to set the app running, click Save (which then tells me that it's saving to the storage card) and then just leave it, using the phone as normal and just wait for the crash to happen?

Comment: Yes, that's Correct :)

Answer (score 1):

logcat might give you some information but that is cleared when the device reboots.

`abd logcat` will connect you to the "rolling log".

logcat is not stored in a file, only in a memory stream but you can easily dump it to file.

`adb logcat -d -v time > logfile.txt`

using the options I listed above will give you a time stamp of when events occur. The `-d` indicates you are dumping to a file, do not "block". `-v time` formats the log with event times.

Instead of `> logfile.txt` you could do `-f /path/to/logfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

[aLogrec](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogrec&hl=en) does basicly the same as Logcat, but writes constantly to a log file on your storage card.

Comment: As of 2014-10-17, aLogrec does not record logs on KitKat (4.4.2). All log files are 0kib. I'm currently looking for alternatives.

Comment: Update: Google changed the READ_LOGS permission in 4.1 (Jelly Bean), which means log reading apps require root in order to read a log other than their own.